# Cassandra OutOfMemoryError

Tags: cassandra, datastax

We are experimenting with using Cassandra as our datastore and have run into an issue with nodes failing due to running out of heap space. We're running Datastax Community Edition with Cassandra 2.0.1 on a 9 node cluster running Ubuntu server 13.04 with 16 GB RAM per node. During a data migration, two of our nodes went down unexpectedly due to running out of heap space. The stack traces in the logs were fairly nondescript and varied. Here's an example of one of them:

```
ERROR [MutationStage:21] 2013-11-01 07:08:39,656 CassandraDaemon.java (line 185) Exception in thread Thread[MutationStage:21,5,main]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(HeapByteBuffer.java:57)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(ByteBuffer.java:331)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.SlabAllocator$Region.init(SlabAllocator.java:178)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.SlabAllocator.getRegion(SlabAllocator.java:101)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.SlabAllocator.allocate(SlabAllocator.java:70)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.Allocator.clone(Allocator.java:30)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.internOrCopy(ColumnFamilyStore.java:2220)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Column.localCopy(Column.java:277)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$1.apply(Memtable.java:107)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$1.apply(Memtable.java:104)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AtomicSortedColumns.addAllWithSizeDelta(AtomicSortedColumns.java:195)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.resolve(Memtable.java:196)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable.put(Memtable.java:160)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.apply(ColumnFamilyStore.java:842)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:373)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Keyspace.apply(Keyspace.java:338)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutation.apply(RowMutation.java:201)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.RowMutationVerbHandler.doVerb(RowMutationVerbHandler.java:56)
    at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessageDeliveryTask.run(MessageDeliveryTask.java:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Prior to this there are AssertionErrors like this:

```
ERROR [FlushWriter:6176] 2013-11-01 06:55:48,825 CassandraDaemon.java (line 185) Exception in thread Thread[FlushWriter:6176,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.rawAppend(SSTableWriter.java:198)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableWriter.append(SSTableWriter.java:186)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.writeSortedContents(Memtable.java:358)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Memtable$FlushRunnable.runWith(Memtable.java:317)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.util.DiskAwareRunnable.runMayThrow(DiskAwareRunnable.java:48)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.WrappedRunnable.run(WrappedRunnable.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

as well as a slew of garbage collection status messages like so:

```
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,923 GCInspector.java (line 116) GC for ConcurrentMarkSweep: 5935 ms for 1 collections, 2963961136 used; max is 3902799872
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,924 StatusLogger.java (line 55) Pool Name                    Active   Pending      Completed   Blocked  All Time Blocked
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,925 StatusLogger.java (line 70) ReadStage                         0         3       58646672         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,925 StatusLogger.java (line 70) RequestResponseStage              0         1       22614351         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,925 StatusLogger.java (line 70) ReadRepairStage                   0         0          76371         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,926 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MutationStage                     7       260      709366463         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,926 StatusLogger.java (line 70) ReplicateOnWriteStage             0         0         104455         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,926 StatusLogger.java (line 70) GossipStage                       0         1        3695467         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,953 StatusLogger.java (line 70) AntiEntropyStage                  0         0            404         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,954 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MigrationStage                    0         0           1178         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,954 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MemtablePostFlusher               1        39          43229         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,955 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MemoryMeter                       0         0            668         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,955 StatusLogger.java (line 70) FlushWriter                       0         0          23228         0                82
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,955 StatusLogger.java (line 70) MiscStage                         0         0            196         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,956 StatusLogger.java (line 70) commitlog_archiver                0         0              0         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,956 StatusLogger.java (line 70) InternalResponseStage             0         0            276         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,956 StatusLogger.java (line 70) HintedHandoff                     0         0             13         0                 0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,956 StatusLogger.java (line 79) CompactionManager                 3        11
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,957 StatusLogger.java (line 81) Commitlog                       n/a       261
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,957 StatusLogger.java (line 93) MessagingService                n/a       1,0
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,957 StatusLogger.java (line 103) Cache Type                     Size                 Capacity               KeysToSave
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,957 StatusLogger.java (line 105) KeyCache                   41783700                104857600                      all
INFO [ScheduledTasks:1] 2013-11-01 06:59:14,975 StatusLogger.java (line 111) RowCache                          0                        0                      all
...
```

Considering this happened after only 4 hours of data ingest, we're wondering why this happened and what we can do prevent it from happening again. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the MAX_HEAP_SIZE set to?

Comment: It's set to 3761M (which I think is the default, 1/4 of the calculated free memory)

Comment: An assertion failure indicates a bug in Cassandra itself. A bug made manifest by something strange you dud, but a bug nonetheless.

Comment: It does depend on a few things here, you may need to tune your JVM settings, but first, what kind of writes are you doing and what does your keyspace and table look like? Also how are your writing to cassandra (i.e. java driver etc). By default MAX_HEAP_SIZE and HEAP_NEWSIZE are not configured by default, typically though these do need configuring. See this link for some more background info: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html

Answer (score -1):

Been running Cassandra on Ubuntu in production for some years and it's really sensitive to the RAM settings. In general, don't store more than 1TB of data per node, and avoid running with less than 8GB of max heap.

See the "MAX_HEAP_SIZE" setting in /etc/cassandra/cassandra-env.sh.

When you initially import data, it goes into RAM, then gets compacted. It's usually a good idea to set the max heap higher for the initial start-up, then restart with a smaller heap once the cluster is fully up.